# How to connect to a Wi-Fi network with a single quote in the SSID from the command line

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I connect to a Wi-Fi network that has a single quote in the SSID from the command line on a Raspberry Pi?

This is the method that I'm using:

```
wpa_cli add_network
wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid '"Your SSID"'
wpa_cli set_network 0 psk '"1234567890"'
```

This will work unless there is a single quote in the SSID. In which case it appears to go into interactive mode, but you can't use it.

```
wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid '"Your ' SSID"'
>
```

I've tried escaping it, but that doesn't make a difference.

```
wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid '"Your \' SSID"'
>
```

It will work in interactive mode, but I'm actually trying to do this from Node.js using the wireless-tools package.

This is my environment:

```
lsb_release -a
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)

uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+

wpa_cli -v
wpa_cli v2.4

$SHELL -version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
```

Comment: This question is much more directly related to your shell, not so much the OS/kernel or the version of the command you're running. What shell?

Comment: It looks like it's `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better ways, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/1454233) StackOverflow answer, replacing `'` with `'"'"'` should do it.

The full explanation is available in that answer, but the gist of it is that the shell interprets strings that are adjacent with no white-space in between as a single parameter. In this case, it's effectively splitting the ssid into three strings (`'"Your '`, `"'"`, and `' SSID"'`) and then combining them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a single-quoted string cannot contain single quotes. However, with bash, there is a 3rd flavour of quoting: [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

```
$ ssid=$'"Your \' SSID"'
$ echo "$ssid"
"Your ' SSID"
```